# find duplicates and list values as columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find duplicates and list values as columns.

Example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A',1],
        ['B',2],
        ['C',3],
        ['D',4],
        ['E',5],
        ['C',6],
        ['D',7],
        ['E',8],
        ['F',9],
        ['G',10]
        
    ],columns=['name','value'])
df = df[df.duplicated(['name'], keep=False)]
print(df)
```

Current output is:
:

```
   name  value
: 2    C      3
: 3    D      4
: 4    E      5
: 5    C      6
: 6    D      7
: 7    E      8
```

expected output:

```
:   name  value1 value2
: 2    C      3       6
: 3    D      4       7
: 4    E      5       8
```

Comment: that means the duplicate allways happens twice?

Comment: Yes, it happen twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
(
    df.groupby('name')
    .value.agg(list)
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(lambda x: f'value{x+1}', axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  name  value1  value2
0    C       3       6
1    D       4       7
2    E       5       8
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
df1 = df[df.duplicated('name', keep='first')].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df[df.duplicated('name', keep='last')].reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
name    value_x value_y
0   C   6   3
1   D   7   4
2   E   8   5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could aggregate the values for each duplicate into a list, then split them out into a separate dataframe which you can concat back to the names:

```py
df = df[df.duplicated(['name'], keep=False)]
gg = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(list)
out = pd.concat([gg['name'], 
    pd.DataFrame(gg['value'].tolist()).add_prefix('value')],
    axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  name  value0  value1
0    C       3       6
1    D       4       7
2    E       5       8
```

Note this will work for arbitrary numbers of values for each duplicate, generating as many columns as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate index:

```
df['suffix'] = df.assign(t=1).groupby('name')['t'].cumcount()
```

Then assign a multi-index, `unstack`, and `dropna`:

```
>>> df.set_index(['name', 'suffix']).unstack().dropna(thresh=2)
       value     
suffix     0    1
name             
C        3.0  6.0
D        4.0  7.0
E        5.0  8.0
```

Pass to `dropna` the parameter `thresh` to require 1 or more duplicates. If you omit `thresh` it will require all columns to be non-NA.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
(dfe:=df.assign(num = df.groupby('name').cumcount() + 1)\
  .pivot(index='name', columns='num'))\
  .set_axis([f'{i}{j}' for i, j in dfe.columns], axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  name  value1  value2
0    C       3       6
1    D       4       7
2    E       5       8
```